# How to access session variable in Mako template and Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

I have this Pyramid view:

```
def ClientView(request):
    session = request.session
    session['selectedclientid'] = 'test' #selectedclient.id
    session.save()
    return dict(
        logged_in=authenticated_userid(request)
    )
```

And then in my template I'm just trying something like this:

```
% if session['selectedclientid'] != None:
                The session has something
            % endif
```

And this gives me a template error:

```
    % if session['selectedclientid'] != None:
TypeError: 'Undefined' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Am I setting the session variable wrong? Am I querying it wrong?  Do I even need to make a copy of the `request.session` object and `.save()` it in the first place?  Couldn't I just do `request.session['myvariable'] = 'foo'` and set it that way?  That still doesn't help me in pulling it back in the template.

Comment: Read this:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/single_file_tasks/single_file_tasks.html

Comment: None is good for python but not in mako UNDEFINED is what should be checked against if looking for a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.session` is the variable in your template. Not `session`. This is why you are getting the `Undefined` exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.  I can still set it like so:

```
request.session['selectedclientid'] = 'test'
```

But reading it back worked like this:

```
% if 'selectedclientid' in request.session:
                The session has something ${request.session['selectedclientid']}
            % endif
```