# Can you set session variables in MAKO files in Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

So I found this answer regarding setting session variables in a pyramid view file, and then later accessing it in a mako template. ( [How to access session variable in Mako template and Pyramid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243500/how-to-access-session-variable-in-mako-template-and-pyramid) )

I wanted to know if you could do it the other way around. So instead of:

Pyramid view.py

```
def thisView(request):
    session = request.session
    session['selectedclientid'] = 'test' #selectedclient.id
    session.save()
```

webpage.mako

```
${request.session['selectedclientid']}
```

Can I swap it so I can do this instead?

webpage.mako

```
${request.session['selectedclientid'] = '5'}
```

Pyramid view.py

```
def thisView(request):
    someLogicOn(session['selectedclientid'])
```

So far I have been unsuccessful in making it work and I'm not sure if it's just due to a lack of understanding how to do it or if it's something that just can't be done. Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the typical rendering workflow, the view executes *before* the renderer. It's not clear how you are intending to correct for that. It's possible to do if you call `render` yourself within the view, I guess, so I'll show that.

webpage.mako:

```
<%
request.session['selectedClientId'] = '5'
%>
```

code:

```
def thisView(request):
    response = render_to_response('webpage.mako', {}, request=request)
    someLogicOn(request.session['selectedClientId'])
    return response
```

This is logically a little backward though, so you might want to think twice about what you're doing.

Comment: Okay, so it is a bit of naivety on my end. I'll consider it, but try to come up with a separate solution altogether. Thanks!